# How to check stripe create session details in payment_intent.succeeded?

Tags: python, stripe-payments, fastapi, payment-gateway

With the help of this function i am creating stripe checkout session which will give me payment url.
I am passing client_reference_id = sender_id in session how can i get this in my payment intent succeeded payload.
How these two is connected help me.

```
def generate_payment_link(sender_id, selected_option_title, email_address): #genrating payment link
    try:
        # Create a Checkout Session
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[{
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'inr',
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': f'{selected_option_title}',
                    },
                    'unit_amount': 10000,  
                },
                'quantity': 1,
                "adjustable_quantity": {
                    "enabled": "True",
                    "maximum": "100",
                    "minimum": "1"
            }, 
                 
            }],
           
            customer_email = email_address,
            client_reference_id = sender_id,
            mode='payment',
            success_url='https://example.com/success',
            cancel_url='https://example.com/cancel',
        )
        
        payment_link = session.get('url') 
        return payment_link
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating payment link: {e}")
```

and receiving in my webhook which is something like this

```
@app.post("/stripe-webhook")
async def webhook(request: Request):
    """ other code""" 
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        print(session)
     
    elif event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        payment_intent = event['data']['object']
        
        send_success_payment_message()
```

I tried my passing metadata but not receiving data on my payment intent succeeded payload

Answer (score 0):

When using Checkout Sessions it's better to listen to `checkout.session.completed` events instead of `payment_intent.succeeded` to fulfill your orders. This is better explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).

##### How to handle failed payments?

We have 3 types of failure for payments in Checkout Sessions:

1. Payment method failed synchronously (e.g. card declines, etc.) this wouldn't trigger any event and will only fail on the front end
2. the payment method is asynchronous (e.g. bank debits, etc.) and you need to wait either `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` or `checkout.session.async_payment_failed` events to know whether the payment got through or not
3. the session expired after by default 24hrs and you receive a `checkout.session.expired` event

Comment: thank you.
so that means `checkout.session.completed` and `payment_intent.succeeded` is not related.

Comment: both will get fired. but you only need to listen to the `checkout.session.completed`.  if you happen to need some data from the underlying Payment Intent, then you can [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve) the Payment Intent using the `payment_intent` [ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_intent) from on the checkout session.

Comment: how can i do for payment failed

Comment: do what exactly?

Comment: In the 'checkout.session.completed' event, I can retrieve the status as 'paid' or 'unpaid,' but it never transitions to 'unpaid.' How can I handle situations where the payment fails due to any reason?

Comment: I updated the answer to cover your question